# Как переместить курсор относительно текущего положения?

Tags: c++, курсор

Изучал я вот этот материал:
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/menurc/cursor-functions
Однако кроме команд SetCursorPos и SetPhysicalCursorPos у меня ничего не работает.
Я могу переместить курсор на абсолютные координаты. Но мне нужно переместить на относительные координаты (относительно курсора). Если вы попробуете считать текущее положение курсора и к переменной добавить +1 например - это будут абсолютные координаты.

```
for (int i = 500; i < 1500; i++)
    {
        Sleep(20);
        SetCursorPos(i, 200);
    }
```

Если вы попробуете переместить курсор влево - у вас ничего не получится, он продолжит двигаться вправо (это абсолютное перемещение).
А вот если бы перемещение было относительным вы бы смогли дёрнуть мышку влево и тогда курсор начал бы перемещаться от 0 до ~1000 координаты (ось Y тоже изменила бы значение)!
Вот мой пример, почему очень важно относительное перемещение: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fcWaSM8Sl4c
Другой вариант, где видно курсор: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJ9L2y-D9vM
Даже если вы покажите, как считать текущее положение курсора - буду крайне признателен.
C++ Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: ¿Так а в чем проблема считать текущие координаты курсора? "ничего не работает" не является описанием проблемы

Comment: постоянные ошибки, которые у меня не получается побороть. Если считать текущие координаты (например в x и у) и перемещать курсор на +1, тогда получится, что x - абсолютная координата, она не будет работать за пределами размера экрана, но при этом на видео я показал, что это возможно. Мой друг делал нечто подобное на Python и у него работало, но если на С++ я ещё хоть что-то понимаю, то на питоне я вообще не понимаю, что происходит. Я бы очень не хотел менять язык.

Comment: "постоянные ошибки, которые у меня не получается побороть. Если считать текущие координаты (например в x и у) и перемещать курсор на +1, тогда получится, что x - абсолютная координата" - приводите [mcve] на видео никакого передвижения курсора вообще не видно, только камера крутится

Comment: Сейчас сделаю видео с перемещение курсора. Смысл где крутится камера: курсор её поворачивает, хоть и вышел за пределы экрана.

Comment: Рука лицо... Камеру крутит не курсор, а мышиный ввод. SetCursorPos устанавливает положение картинки курсора на экране

Comment: Дак подскажите пожалуйста, как такое сделать, я ещё больше запутался... Вот демонстрация в 2 программах, я пытался дёргать курсор и нарисовать круги:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJ9L2y-D9vM

Comment: Если вы собираетесь эмулировать ввод, чтобы управлять сторонним приложением, то это никак не связано с перемещением курсора. А так у вас типичная проблема XY.

Comment: Что за типичная проблема я не знаю, у меня ещё нет ни одной программы на С++ (за исключением тренировки с циклами и т.д.) Если вам не сложно, можете написать (объяснить), что нужно сделать, для эмуляции ввода? Какую мне ввести команду?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_XY_(%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0) и https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput

Answer (score 0):

Вынес это в отдельную функцию:

```
int MOVER(int X, int Y)
{
    INPUT Inputs;
    Inputs.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    Inputs.mi.dx = X;
    Inputs.mi.dy = Y;
    Inputs.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
    SendInput(1, &Inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
    ZeroMemory(&Inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
    return 0;
}
```

Например: если нужно переместить мышку с X1: 100 и Y1: 50 на X2: 50 и Y2: 50, тогда необходимо передать функции значение X: -50 и Y: 0
Это работает в 3D играх!

Примечание: чтобы функция перемещала на точное значение как у меня на -50, а не на -56 и т.д. нужно отключить в параметрах windows ускорение мыши.